# Unable to delete the subscriptions for deleted topics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I created two topics and then later subscriptions associated with them. After few days I deleted the topics but since subscription were pending, I was not able to delete them

After few weeks I saw the subscriptions are still in "Confirmation Pending" state and in some amazon-aws forum I read, pending subscription requests are automatically deleted after 3 days if not confirmed. So now I manually tried to delete those pending requests and I am getting this error

```
Error code: NotFound - Error message: Topic does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here. A SNS subscription was hanging around for more than 72 hours/3 days and had to raise a ticket with AWS to delete it manually from the backend. Looks like there is no other solution than to raise a ticket with AWS.

Comment: Will they entertain request from basic support plan or do i have to purchase their other support plan?

Comment: I had the AWS basic plan and did it for me, but with the basic plan there isn't any technical support - try your luck :) btw, the hanging subscriptions is not a big deal, but is a bit irritating to see them around.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon SNS now supports faster automatic deletion of unconfirmed subscriptions. This reduces the time for Amazon SNS to delete your unconfirmed subscriptions, from the previous 72 hours down to 48 hours. This applies to all new subscriptions and does not require any on-boarding.

For more information, see: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/05/amazon-sns-automatic-deletion-unconfirmed-subscriptions/