# Can't delete pending subscriptions with deleted topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I created some subscriptions through CDK, but needed to delete the stack on the GUI. When deleting the stack, the topics were deleted but the subscriptions unlinked, and not deleted.

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64567793/unable-to-delete-the-subscriptions-for-deleted-topics) that it wasn't possible to delete a subscription with no topic before, is this still the case? Do I still need to open a ticket to AWS Support?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: if its pending confirmation, After 3 days it should be automatically deleted. if not you need to open a ticket with aws support. ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-delete-subscription-topic.html

Comment: Ah, thank you! I saw that page so many times but must've skipped the beginning of it...
Still, there should be a way to delete it even if it's pending confirmation =/